# PHP MYSQL Configuring a Update Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have the following `if statement` that works fine for an `insert` but I cannot seem to get it to only update the table with items that are not inserted:

**Insert:**

```
        for($i=0; $i<count($fields['Occupation']); $i++) {
            $id = $fields['Occupation'][$i];

           CMS::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id));
        }
            echo 'found update';
```

I have tried the following **update** line with no luck.

```
CMS::updateQuery("UPDATE {refocus_candidate_category} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id));
```

**Full Statement:**

```
$catParams = array_merge(array($emailCheck['id']), $fields['Occupation']);
$catPlaceholders = '?'.str_repeat(',?',count($fields['Occupation'])-1);

$catCheck = CMS::selectQuery("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid IN (".$catPlaceholders.")", $catParams);

if($catCheck != FALSE)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($fields['Occupation']); $i++) {
        $id = $fields['Occupation'][$i];

        CMS::updateQuery("UPDATE {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id));
    }
        echo 'found update'l
}else{
    for($i=0; $i<count($fields['Occupation']); $i++) {
        $id = $fields['Occupation'][$i];

        CMS::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {table} SET canid=?, categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $id));
    }
    echo 'else insert';
}
```

Comment: post the code you are trying for the update, the full one

Comment: You have four parameters in your update query but you are providing only two values..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess you need something like following code:

```
CMS::updateQuery("UPDATE {refocus_candidate_category} SET canid=?,
                  categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?",
                  array($emailCheck['id'], $id, $emailCheck['id'], $id)
                );
```

Basically you need as many array elements as `?` in your `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Thanks alot,  but currently it will not insert any new selected options - keep the current inserted items but update with any new selected items.  How could I make it do this

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're two array items short:

```
CMS::updateQuery("UPDATE {refocus_candidate_category} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array(
    emailCheck['id'], $id, ,'canid', 'cat_id number here');
);
```